# Bluetooth low energy Support in 6.0

Tags: android, bluetooth, gps

I am trying to develop an android application which uses Bluetooth low energy devices like eddystone(Estimote) beacons.

It worked fine in lollipop but stopped working in android 6.0. It is working when gps is enabled in the device to use GPS feature i am requesting permission from the user every time which make user to get irritated.  Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [issue](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/301) on some device ROMs, notably 6.0 builds for the Nexus 5 and Nexus 5X where **Bluetooth LE devices cannot be detected unless Location Services are on in Settings.**  To adjust this, go to Settings -> Location.

Note, however, that this Location setting is not specific to GPS.  You can switch from "High accuracy" Location mode to "Battery saving" which will not use GPS, and beacon detections will still work.

Because this behavior is not universal across Android 6.0 ROMs, it is unclear whether the requirement to have Location enabled is a bug or an intended feature that Google has simply not rolled out consistently.  Below are devices ROMS for which I have info:

```
                  Build   Location
Device   Version  number  required?
------   -------  ------  --------
Nexus 9  6.0      MPA44I  NO
Nexus 5X 6.0      MDB08I  YES
Nexus 5  6.0      MRA58K  YES
```